# Flask problem TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)

Tags: python, flask

I can't solve the error I get, I would be glad if you help me

problem :

```
cls._instance = super(MateDealer, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```
sc = SessionController(db, User, Product, Vend)
```

```
import sys
import os
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
from flask_serial import Serial
from threading import Thread

class SessionController:

    def __init__(self, db, user, product, vend):
        self.db = db
        self.timer = None
        self._lock = False
        self.product = product
        self.vend = vend
        self.user = user
        self.active_user = ""
        self.md = MateDealer(self)
        self.md.start()
        self.user_id = None

    def is_locked(self):
        return self._lock

    def vend_start(self, user_id):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.lock()
        user = self.user.query.get(self.user_id)
        self.active_user = user.name 
        self.md.start_session(user.balance)

    def vend_request(self, item):
        product = self.product.query.filter_by(slot=item).first()
        print (product)
        user = self.user.query.get(self.user_id)
        print (user)
        if user.balance >= product.price:
            self.md.approve_vend(product.price)
        else:
            self.md.deny_vend()

    def vend_success(self, item):
        product = self.product.query.filter_by(slot=item).first()
        product.stock -= 1
        user = self.user.query.get(self.user_id)
        user.balance -= product.price
        vend = self.vend(user.name, product.name, product.price, datetime.now())
        self.db.session.add(vend)
        self.db.session.commit()
        self.cancel()

    def lock(self):
        self._lock = True

    def unlock(self):
        self._lock = False

    def cancel(self):
        if self.timer != None:
            self.timer.stop()
            self.timer = None
        self.active_user = ""
        self.unlock()
        self.md.cancel_session()


class Timer(Thread):

    def __init__(self, time, callback):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.time = time
        self.callback = callback
        self.canceled = False

    def run(self):
        while self.time > 0 and not self.canceled:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.time -= 1

        if not self.canceled:
            self.callback()

    def stop(self):
        self.canceled = True


class MateDealer(Thread):
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super(MateDealer, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance

    def __init__(self, sc, *args, **kwargs):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.sc = sc
        self.serial = Serial()
        self.serial.port = '/dev/ttyACM0'
        self.serial.baudrate = 38400
        self.serial.bytesize = 8
        self.serial.parity = 'N'
        self.serial.stopbits = 1
        self.serial.timeout = 0.1
        self.running = False

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.serial.open()
        except Exception as e:
            print >> sys.stderr, e.message
            return

        print (self.serial)
        self.running = True
        msg = ''
        while self.running:
            byte = self.serial.read()
            if byte != '':
                msg += byte
            if msg.endswith('\n'):
                self.parse_cmd(msg)
                msg = ''

        if self.serial.is_open():
            self.serial.close()

    def start_session(self, balance):
        self.serial.write('start-session %d\r\n' % balance)
        print ('start-session %d' % balance)

    def approve_vend(self, price):
        self.serial.write('approve-vend %d\r\n' % price)
        print ('approve-vend %d\r\n' % price)

    def deny_vend(self):
        self.serial.write('deny-vend\r\n')
        print ('deny-vend')

    def cancel_session(self):
        self.serial.write('cancel-session\r\n')
        print ('cancel-session')

    def parse_cmd(self, cmd):
        cmd = cmd.strip()
        if cmd.startswith('vend-request'):
            _cmd, price, item = cmd.split(' ')
            self.sc.vend_request(item)
        elif cmd.startswith('vend-success'):
            _cmd, item = cmd.split(' ')
            self.sc.vend_success(item)
        elif cmd.startswith('session-complete'):
            self.sc.cancel()
        else:
            print (cmd)
```

changing with python 2

```
         cls._instance = super(MateDealer, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

i deleted it and for python3

```
         cls._instance = super().__new__()
```

i tried but it doesn't work

I tried all google and stack overflow errors, but I couldn't get it to work, I would appreciate it if you could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3, you need to not pass any additional arguments to the `__new__` call, so you need:

```
cls._instance = super().__new__(cls)
```

Although note, a potential problem with your implementation is that

```
 __init__
```

will be run again each time you call `MateDealer()`... which is not what you want, I surmise, from the fact that you seem to be trying to create some sort of singleton. What exactly is the purpose of what you are doing here?

If you just want a "singleton" don't even bother with all of this. Just define a factory function that caches the instance and a "private" class, so quick-and-dirty:

```
class _MateDealer(Thread):
    def __init__(self, sc, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.sc = sc
        self.serial = Serial()
        self.serial.port = '/dev/ttyACM0'
        self.serial.baudrate = 38400
        self.serial.bytesize = 8
        self.serial.parity = 'N'
        self.serial.stopbits = 1
        self.serial.timeout = 0.1
        self.running = False

__instance = None

def MateDealer(sc, *args, **kwargs):
    global __instance
    if __instance is None:
        __instance = _MateDealer(sc, *args, **kwargs)
    return _mate_instance
```

Comment: hello its not work TypeError: Serial.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'app'

I am sharing the whole code above.

Comment: @msvasilis that looks like a completely unrelated error, due to how `Serial` is being initialized. I don't really use flask, but it doesn't have anything to do with this

Comment: I shared the whole code above, can you take a look if it won't tire you?

Comment: @msvasilis I'm sorry, but this is not your personal debugging service. It's a question-and-answer site. But as I stated, this has something to do with how you instantiate `Serial` which seems to expect the `app` parameter, which you clearly aren't providing any argument for.

Comment: @msvasilis you aren't actually using `flask`, so I'm not sure why you are using `flask_serial`, which is just some random repository as far as I can tell, and it hasn't been updated in like 5 years and has no real documentation: https://github.com/RedFalsh/flask-serial/blob/master/README.md

Comment: https://github.com/makerslocal/matedealer
I want to run this repo but I couldn't run it, it's a bit old but I need it right now I'm very inadequate in python

Comment: class MateDealer(Thread):


    def __init__(self, sc, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.serial = Serial()
        self.sc = sc
        self.serial.port = '/dev/ttyACM0'
        self.serial.baudrate = 38400
        self.serial.bytesize = 8
        self.serial.parity = 'N'
        self.serial.stopbits = 1
        self.serial.timeout = 0.1
        self.running = False
    _instance = None
    def MateDealer(sc, *args, **kwargs):
        global __instance
        ...
    i solved and try import serial sdk thank you bro realy thank you

Comment: @msvasilis I'm sorry, but that seems to have *nothing* to do with flask or the code you have above. again, I'm sorry, but this is not your personal debugging service. I suggest you look for an appropriate subreddit if you want to ask these sorts of open-ended questions

Comment: thank you bro, realy thank you you are gorgeous, you solved this